# How to create a new Folder structure as same as Existing in Tridion using core service

Tags: 2011, core-service, 2011-sp1

I am new to tridion, I want to create a new folder structure same as existing folder structure by using core service 2011.

My folder structure looks like below

[image]

I need to create new folder structure same as "2014 News" folder structure and It should contain same sub folder structures as well.

Comment: What code have you already tried?

Comment: Two things to consider as you approach this requirement: 1. the "context-free" names like "2014 News" are useful when needing to know the folder anywhere. _But_ if you can get away with removing the year from the month folders, then this could be done with just copy&paste. 2. If the editors organize items like this a lot, consider making your code generic enough to copy a set of any folders (with maybe a date parameter). :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First follow something like this post to get all the folders recursively

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12018111/get-all-folders-of-a-publication-using-core-service

Then this post can help you with creating the new folders

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9905021/how-to-create-folder-structure-in-sdl-tridion-2011-sp1-using-core-service

Answer (score 2):

You just need to know how to create folders within other folders, then add some simple C# looping and formatting logic.

```
var formatInfo = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat;

var parentFolderUrl = "/webdav/Test Publication/Building Blocks/Content/50 News";

var yearFolder = (FolderData) client.GetDefaultData(ItemType.Folder, parentFolderUrl);

yearFolder.Title = String.Format("2015 News");

yearFolder = (FolderData) client.Save(yearFolder, new ReadOptions());

for (int month = 1; month <= 12; month++)
{
    var monthFolder = (FolderData) client.GetDefaultData(ItemType.Folder, yearFolder.Id);

    monthFolder.Title = String.Format("2015-{0:D2} {1} News",
                            month,
                            formatInfo.GetMonthName(month));

    client.Save(monthFolder, null);
}
```